# Splitting WP_Query Results into different sections and adding headers

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically I have a WP_Query that outputs all the posts alphabetically. Now I need to divide these posts into sections depending on their first letter so something like the following

List all posts with a

List all posts with b

The problem is that I want to include divs, and those divs need to only run once, instead of multiple times for example

```
    <div class="letterA">
        <div class="title">A</div>
            My list of A posts 
    </div>

    <div class="letterB">
        <div class="title">B</div>
            My list of B posts 
    </div>

... and so on until Z
```

These divs will only run once and they are specific to each letter. My current solution has if statements going from letter a to letter z and just as many signal variables to accomplish it. I feel that this can be done a lot more efficiently, and I am wondering if someone has a better idea where I don't have to do so many ifs.

Here is my current code for it: http://pastebin.com/UnUqQWcN

Comment: Yes, if you have `$checkA`, `$checkB`, ... `$checkZ` variables, you probably want to read up on [arrays](http://php.net/array) and loops. But ordering the results in the database and splitting off the first letter would also work..

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it will certainly save some 'if' statements.

During each iteration of the loop, keep track of the last post's first letter.

ex, assuming posts are already in alphabetical order:

```
$lastLetter = '';
while ( have_posts() ) {

    the_post(); 

    $currentLetter = strtolower(substr(get_the_title(), 0, 1));

    if ($currentLetter != $lastLetter) {
        // do custom nav header code
    }

    // do list of links content here

    $lastLetter = $currentLetter;

}
```